# Retrieving a value from a PHP file via AJAX call and posting to <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to retrieve a value from a .php file I have that currently calculates a percentage from like & dislike buttons.  I'm trying to use an AJAX call to perform this but it is not displaying the value in the specified  tag

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: 'variables.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#content2 span").html(result['percentage']);
    }

});
```

PHP file (variables.php):

```
<?php
//COUNTS THE NUMBER OF LIKES & DISLIKES AND TOTAL NUMBER OF RATINGS
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $ratings_table WHERE id='$id' AND rating='like'");
$likes = mysql_num_rows($q);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $ratings_table WHERE id='$id' AND rating='dislike'");
$dislikes = mysql_num_rows($q);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $ratings_table WHERE id='$id'");
$all_ratings = mysql_num_rows($q);

//PERCENTAGE OF RATINGS THAT CONSIST OF LIKES
$percentage = 0;
if($all_ratings){
    $percentage = floor($likes/$all_ratings*100);
}

//THE LARGER LIKE IMAGE URL
$l_p = 'http://wcetdesigns.com/images/buttons/l_color.png';

//SMALLER LIKE & DISLIKE IMAGES
$l = 'http://wcetdesigns.com/images/buttons/l_color15.png';
$d = 'http://wcetdesigns.com/images/buttons/d_color15.png';

//CHECKS IF USER HAS ALREADY RATED CONTENT
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $ratings_table WHERE id='$id' AND ip='$ip'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

//IF SO, THE LIKE OR DISLIKE BUTTON WILL HAVE A SHADOW
if($r["rating"]=="like"){
    $l = 'http://wcetdesigns.com/images/buttons/l_color_shadow15.png';
}
if($r["rating"]=="dislike"){
    $d = 'http://wcetdesigns.com/images/buttons/d_color_shadow15.png';
}

//CONTENT, PERCENTAGE, AND THE BUTTONS TOGETHER
$m .= '<div class="content'.$id.'">
<img id="like_percentage" src="'.$l_p.'"><span id="percentage">'.$percentage.'%</span>   <br>
<img id="like" onClick="rate($(this).attr(\'id\'), '.$id.')" src="'.$l.'"> <img     id="dislike" onClick="rate($(this).attr(\'id\'), '.$id.')" src="'.$d.'">
</div>
';



?>
```

The php file above was originally included within another .php file and runs fine but I want to display the value in the percentage variable per ID in separate  tags on an html page.

Do I have to modify my AJAX call?

Comment: Do you echo anything in the PHP? did you try `console.log(result);` inside the `success` function?

Comment: Did you want a `JSON` response? like so: `echo json_encode($r);` where $r is your `mysql result` if there was more than 1 result use a `while` loop to push to an array, then echo that array.

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP echo the variable m;

```
echo $m;
```

On the javascript do this on the success function;

```
 $("#content2 span").html(result);
```

Also set $.ajax dataType to text:

```
dataType:'text'
```

Regards.

Comment: I was actually pulling the wrong .php file into my AJAX call.  Works fine now, thank you!

Comment: LOL, oukey, great what matters is that's working ;) . don't forget to mark as answer please. regards.